# What did Moses learn during the second ascent?

Tags: torah-study, moshe-rabbeinu, kabbalat-hatorah

If I understand right Moses spent the first 40 days, from 7 of Sivan to 17 of Tamuz studying the "whole Torah". The Gemora (Nedarim 38a) says he learned and forgot until G-d gave Moses the Torah as a present.

After the Golden Calf accident, Moses comes up for another 40 days round and to receive the second pair of Luchos.

What did Moses learn in those second 40 days as different from the first ones?

Comment: There must be a good reason why it's not written in Torah. We will probably never know. But the fact that his face was 'radiant' and he saw 'the back of the lord' means that it was far out of our scope. It was something that went far beyond our (phyical) understanding.